# Debugging an application running in windows CE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, smart-device

I have created an application in vs 2008 - Smart Device project with .NET compact framework 3.5 to run on windows CE 6.0

I run this application on a device where Windows CE 6.0 is installed.

I want to debug this application from my machine ( Windows 7 with vs 2008 installed) while it is running on Windows CE.
Can anybody help me on this please?

Comment: What have you tried?  It should be as simple as 1. Connect the PC to the device (using corecon over Ethernet, preferably) 2. Press F5 to debug.

Comment: thanks @ctacke, I am able to do it using ethernet, but I want to do it by connecting ce device via serial port

Answer (score 0):

You should install Windows Mobile DeviceCenter on your PC and connect the device over USB (and maybe the cradle) to your PC. After your DeviceCenter has the connection you can start debugging, but you have to select the right target-device (default is a device-emulation).